# Can ng-click get the id of the parent div as parameter?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

When i have got the following for example:

```
<div id="a-div-id">
    <img ng-src="{{image.image}}" ng-click="select(image.id)" />
</div>
```

Can i somehow pass the id `a-div-id` of the div element to the `ng-click` function `select()` as a parameter? Otherwise i would have to store the id of the div inside my image objekt. That would not be very nice.

Comment: it is definitely possible to reference this if you really need to, but in Angular, if you have to reference your DOM, you are probably doing something wrong.  There's not really enough context here to understand why this is necessary.

Comment: i could do it on a different way. what i want to do is to set a border around the clicked element. i have to do it in javascript. the problem is that i have many different elements with different id's and classes and some are display="block" some are display="none" so i have to check the id's so that i know on which element i have to set the border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can access **$event**.

From [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)

> $event Directives like ngClick and ngFocus expose a $event object
>   within the scope of that expression. The object is an instance of a
>   jQuery Event Object when jQuery is present or a similar jqLite object.

So your code would look like:

```js
$scope.select= function(imageId, clickEvent) {
      $scope.myParentId= clickEvent.target.parentElement.id;
      $scope.mySelectedImageId = imageId;
    };
```

I did a [plnkr where you can reproduce it](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mkx17v?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it also without using the controller:

```
<div ng-init="theId = 'hello'" id="{{theId}}">
   <img ng-src="{{image.image}}" ng-click="select(theId)" />
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/6L9hb0n5/)

Comment: unless this is contained in an ng-repeat, This is [not the appropriate use of ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#!).  `ng-init` is a directive, which has a priority, and may not run exactly in the order you expect.  Writing code that relies upon this value without knowing when the directive will calculate this value is a recipe for disaster.